# Create New Mapset (GRASS) in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-3

How do i create a new mapset from QGIS 3.2 for GRASS?

I can´t find the Plugin GRASS in manage and install plugins...

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the ***QGIS 3.2.0 Desktop with GRASS 7.4.1.exe*** file to load GRASS with QGIS.

If using Windows, you can find this in

```
Start > All Programs > QGIS 3.2 > QGIS 3.2.0 Desktop with GRASS 7.4.1
```